# SharePoint O365 Resources

Tags: sharepoint-online, resources

How much will be resources affect the performance of a SharePoint Site Collection? There are sites which I have created have 0 resources and there are a few with 300 resources. I can't find any difference. Can anyone tell me what could be the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource usage quota is a site collection metric calculated by **SharePoint Online**. The main purpose of resource quota's is to `limit the risk` that sand-boxed custom code can have on available resources on a site collection, bad code causing excessive CPU use for example.

The actual resource quota used to be determined by the number of user seats in your company's subscription `(#seats×200) +300 (may have changed now)`.

So for a `10 seat license`, the resource quota would be `2300 split across all site collections` you own.

If I remember correctly(not looked at this for a while), if you `increase` the quote in one site collection, then you must `decrease` it in another or buy more quota.  If you don't have any custom code you can probably just leave it at the default.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, Microsoft is using the "resources" word purposefully to be vague. It is a vague reference to memory and CPU time. My guess is that microsoft didn't want to make any promises when it comes to CPU or memory, so we get "resources". Smart, and fairly humorous.

So, to answer your question, "resources" is the maximum amount of relative CPU and memory allocated to a site collection and or site collection group.

The actual CPU in MHertz and memory in MBs is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Both these answers are close but not quite right. "Resources" refers to .NET code running in sandbox solutions. Since sandbox code is no longer allowed in SharePoint Online, the Resource metric is **completely meaningless**. I always set this value to zero when provisioning sites.

Feel free to ignore it.